# Не работает таймер

Tags: c#

Почему не выводит строку?

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class program
{
    public static Timer nTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        NewTimer();
    }

    public static void NewTimer()
    {
        nTimer = new Timer(2000);
        nTimer.Elapsed += TimerCall;
        nTimer.AutoReset = true;
        nTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public static void TimerCall(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Вывод");
    }
}
```

Comment: Программа завершается раньше, чем он срабатывает

Comment: @Андрей: Почему не как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программа завершается раньше, чем ваш таймер срабатывает. Как избежать этого - зависит от контекста, возможно таймер тут вообще не нужен. Но если чисто из академического интереса - можете добавить что-то типа `Console.ReadKey();`, это не позволит программе завершиться самопроизвольно.